# Einstein Bot Custom vs Context Variable

Tags: einstein, bots, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

What is the difference between context vs custom variable when configuring Einstein bot?

Comment: You can get an overview from this article - [https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_whats_a_variable.htm&type=5](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_whats_a_variable.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

Custom variables can be considered as data containers and can just used to put and retrieve data. They don't have any related mappings.

[image]

While [context variables](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_custom_context_variables.htm&type=5) can be leveraged as sophisticated formulas which grab content from either `LiveChatTranscript` for the Chat channel or `MessagingSession` or `MessagingUser`for the Messaging Channels.

[image]